# Having a gesturebuilder in my own application

Tags: android

I want to have a gesturebuilder in my own application.I want to store the gestures entered by the user and use it later.How do i do this?How do i call the gesturebuilder from my application.Or is there an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with the sample gesturebuilder activity and use that as a base: its in the `samples` folder at `GestureBuilder\src\com\android\gesture\builder\*`.

Comment: Look in your Android SDK folder: in my case its installed in `C:\projects\Android\android-sdk-windows-1.5_r1`. There is a `samples` folder that has a subfolder for each version of Android.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you some links that describes the gesture recognition. May be it will be useful for you have a look: http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/, http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html